# Postgres: Read CONSTRAINTS definition

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint

I'm able to read CONSTRAINTS in the Information Schema, but how can I get all parameters associated with that CONSTRAINTS to get a full CONSTRAINTS definition by using SQL ?
For example,

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

This will give me list of CONSTRAINTS, but let say, I got a CONSTRAINTS FOREIGN KEY  "user_role_id" and its full definition (via pgAdmin) is

```
ALTER TABLE app.user
ADD CONSTRAINT user_role_id FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
REFERENCES app.role (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So how do I get this definition by just writing SQL that give me all those options associated with that CONSTRAINTS?

Comment: There are many more tables in the Information Schema; see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/information-schema.html
In addition, you should probably be using the Postgres-specific system catalogs, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalogs.html

Comment: But the real Postgres-way to do this is to use pg_get_constraintdef() and other similar functions. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solve my problem

```
    SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_from
      ,conname
      ,pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p ')
AND    n.nspname = 'public' -- your schema here
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```